# PK11_Sign with padding

Tags: hash, cryptography, mozilla, pkcs#11, nss

From http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tech-notes/tn7.html, it states that

> For a low level signature, use PK11_Sign(). Both of these functions do
>   the PKCS #1 wrapping of the data. PK11_Sign does not do the BER
>   encoding of the hash (as is done in SGN_ functions)

From the code API

```
/*
 * sign a hash. The algorithm is determined by the key.
 */
SECStatus
PK11_Sign(SECKEYPrivateKey *key, SECItem *sig, const SECItem *hash)
```

Q1) My PK11_Sign functions result in invalid signature. The input of the hash->data is a7cd893b31b0ea44ed1aa7cafcda658744cc5a02ef26feccceaae9a8becb83a0 hash of SHA-256, from "Hello SHA-256". The data->len is 64. Then, the code perform a hexadecimal to binary. Then i pass these info to PK11_Sign. Did i miss any steps?

Q2) What does it mean by BER encoding of hash? If we have a string of hash in hexdecimel, then we convert it to binary of hash, that is the BER? Or the sentence means, it only support DER?

Q3) Any sample of PK11_Sign similar to the operation as above?

Answer (score 1):

Q1: Yes, you need to prepend the hash value with the ASN.1 / DER encoding of the OID of SHA-256 plus the tag and length of the hash value itself.

Q2: BER are the Basic Encoding Rules of ASN.1, it's a binary Tag-Length-Value (TLV) encoding of data that is structured according to ASN.1 definitions. DER is a *canonical subset* of BER. You should definitely use DER here.

Q3: Well, no, but I think I can speed up things for you as creating or even learning about ASN.1 is rather time consuming. As the OID (identifier of the hash algorithm) and the length of the hash remain static, the DER encoding is static as well. So you can just prefix the following hexadecimals to the hash of your choice.

---

RSA PKCS#1 2.1 (and 2.2) section 9.2 note 1:

> 1. For the six hash functions mentioned in Appendix B.1, the DER
>        encoding T of the DigestInfo value is equal to the following:

```
  MD2:     (0x)30 20 30 0c 06 08 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 02 02 05 00 04
               10 || H.
  MD5:     (0x)30 20 30 0c 06 08 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 02 05 05 00 04
               10 || H.
  SHA-1:   (0x)30 21 30 09 06 05 2b 0e 03 02 1a 05 00 04 14 || H.
  SHA-256: (0x)30 31 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01 05 00
               04 20 || H.
  SHA-384: (0x)30 41 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 02 05 00
               04 30 || H.
  SHA-512: (0x)30 51 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 03 05 00
                  04 40 || H.
```

---

Note that if you do everything correctly then you should be able to treat everything directly as binary at runtime; there should not be a need to first encode the output of the hash to binary, and then back again.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Finally i got a valid signature, based on your answer on Q1.

Comment: Glad it helped, don't forget to hit accept if you find answers that suite you (V mark on the left). I notice you don't have any accepts up till now, which indicates that you either don't know or that you didn't get any useful/complete answers yet.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer Q1 as I am not familiar with NSS APIs but I think Q2 is fairly easy to answer.

When you create signature following RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signature scheme defined in PKCS#1 ([RFC3447](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt)) you need to compute hash value first and put it into DigestInfo structure:

```
DigestInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    digestAlgorithm AlgorithmIdentifier,
    digest OCTET STRING
}
```

DigestInfo then needs to be BER encoded and encrypted with the private key. So you are not encrypting only raw hash value but BER encoded DigestInfo structure which contains raw hash value along with the hash algorithm OID.